# How do I solve 'Those rows are out of bounds.' on Google Sheets?

Tags: google-apps-script

This is the script I have currently. I just picked up script editing recently and I cant resolve this issue.
I am trying to delete the same row in 2 sheets.

```
var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
  var s = ss.getSheetByName('Verification');
  var r = s.getRange('Q:Q');
  var v = r.getValues();
  for(var i=v.length-1;i>=0;i--)
    if(v[0,i] == 'Cancelled')
      s.deleteRow(i+1);
        ss.getSheetByName('S4 Branch');
        s.deleteRow(i+1);
```

Comment: You should debug this by logging some message inside your for loop. As it stands, we don't know where your code breaks, since we have no idea what your spreadsheet looks like.

Answer (score 0):

I believe your goal as follows.

- You want to check the values of the column "Q" of "Verification" sheet.
- When the value is `Cancelled`, you want to delete the row, and also, you want to delete the row of the same row number in "S4 Branch" sheet.

#### Modification points:

- If you want to compare the value of `Cancelled` with `v`, please modify `if(v[0,i] == 'Cancelled')` to `if(v[i][0] == 'Cancelled')`.
- When `var r = s.getRange('Q1:Q' + s.getLastRow());` is used as the data range instead of `var r = s.getRange('Q:Q');`, the process cost will be able to be reduced a little.
- In your script, the if statement and the for loop are not enclosed by `{` and `}`. By this, each script is used for just under the line. For example, `for(var i=v.length-1;i>=0;i--)` is used for `if(v[0,i] == 'Cancelled')`. And, `if(v[0,i] == 'Cancelled')` is used for `s.deleteRow(i+1);`. By this, `i` at `s.deleteRow(i+1);` is always `-1`. So `s.deleteRow(0);` is run. In this case, an error occurs. I think that this might be the reason of your issue.

When above points are reflected to your script, it becomes as follows.

#### Modified script:

```
function myFunction() {
  var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
  var s = ss.getSheetByName('Verification');
  var r = s.getRange('Q1:Q' + s.getLastRow());
  var v = r.getValues();
  var s2 = ss.getSheetByName("S4 Branch");
  for (var i = v.length - 1; i >= 0; i--) {
    if (v[i][0] == 'Cancelled') {
      s.deleteRow(i + 1);
      s2.deleteRow(i + 1);
    }
  }
}
```

#### References:

- [getLastRow()](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/spreadsheet/sheet#getlastrow)
- [deleteRow(rowPosition)](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/spreadsheet/sheet#deleterowrowposition)

Answer (score 0):

If you want to try the below script:

You can add more sheets by updating the **sheetArr** list and it can auto-trigger on Edit.

```
function onEdit() {
  
  deleteRow();
  
 }

function deleteRow() {
  var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
  var sheetArr = ['Verification', 'S4 Branch'];
  for (var i = 0; i<sheetArr.length; i++){
        var lr = ss.getSheetByName(sheetArr[i]).getDataRange().getLastRow();
        var s = ss.getSheetByName(sheetArr[i]).getRange('Q1:Q' + lr ).getValues();
          for (var j = s.length -1; j >= 0; j--){
              if (s[j] == 'Cancelled'){
                delrow = ss.getSheetByName(sheetArr[i]).deleteRow(j+1);          
              }
          } 
  }
}
```